# Individual input values won't change

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm attempting to loop through a set of inputs and have their color value be the value of a specific CSS variable using `style.setProperty`. Each CSS variable corresponds to part of syntax highlighting.

example: `--function-color: #DD4A68` would be the color set for a function in a code block/markdown.

I've set it up to do this dynamically on input change, but the result is that the entire code preview container is colored with the selected color and not individual pieces of code.

**Before changing any values**

[image]

**After changing the "keyword-color" value.**

[image]

The keyword color in the code sample should have been the only thing that changed.

Here's the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fbijx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to get a better sense.

**Color Picker Component**

```
function ColorPickerSection() {
  const [colorVal, setColorVal] = useState(colors)

  const handleInputChange = () => {
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    inputs.forEach(input => {
      input.addEventListener('change', getInputVal)
    })
  }

  const getInputVal = (e) => {
    for (let option of Object.keys(colors)) {
      const root = document.querySelector(':root')
      root.style.setProperty(`--${option}`, e.target.value);
    }
  }

  const onColorChange = (e, colorValKey) => {
    setColorVal({
      ...colors,
      [colorValKey]: e.target.value
    })
    handleInputChange()
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(colorSelect).map(groupName => {
        return (<div key={groupName}>
          <GroupName>{groupName}</GroupName>
          {Object.keys(colorSelect[groupName]).map(color => {
            return (
              <ColorPicker
                id={color}
                key={color}
                label={color}
                value={colorVal[color]}
                onChange={(e) => onColorChange(e, color)}
              />
            )
          })}
        </div>)
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default ColorPickerSection
```

**Helper Object that stores all the colors and property names**

```
const colorSelect = {
  'Line Highlights': {
    'highlight-background': '#F7EBC6',
    'highlight-accent': '#F7D87C'
  },
  'Inline Code': {
    'inline-code-color': '#DB4C69',
    'inline-code-background': '#F9F2F4'
  },
  'Code Blocks': {
    'block-background': '#F8F5EC',
    'base-color': '#5C6E74',
    'selected-color': '#b3d4fc'
  },
  'Tokens': {
    'comment-color': '#93A1A1',
    'punctuation-color': '#999999',
    'property-color': '#990055',
    'selector-color': '#669900',
    'operator-color': '#a67f59',
    'operator-background': '#FFFFFF',
    'variable-color': '#ee9900',
    'function-color': '#DD4A68',
    'keyword-color': '#0077aa'
  }
}

const colorNames = []
const colors = {}

Object.keys(colorSelect).map(key => {
  const group = colorSelect[key]
  Object.keys(group).map(color => {
    colorNames.push(color)
    colors[color] = group[color]
  })
})

export { colorSelect, colorNames, colors }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `ColorPicker` component --> Change your `onColorChange` to `onChange` as you already assigned your function to `onChange` while passing as props.

```
return (
    <ColorPickerContainer>
      <p>{props.label}</p>
      <ColorSwatch type="color" value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange} />
      <HexInput
        type="text"
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.onChange}
      />
    </ColorPickerContainer>
  );
```

instead of

```
   <ColorSwatch type="color" value={props.value} onChange={props.onColorChange} />
      <HexInput
        type="text"
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.onColorChange}
      />
```

Comment: Thank you, but even with that, I still have the same issue. When I click on any input, the entire code snippet preview changes color and not the specific line as intended.